# How to use routerLink with two html's

Tags: angular, angular7

So, I'm trying to makeing two seprate routerLinks with the same component but they have different html views. the problem is that it keeps giving me the Error of: "Error: Cannot match any routes".

This is the code I'm trying to implement:

```
{
    path: 'home', 
    component: HomeComponent,
}, 
{
   path: 'homeInfo/:id', 
   component: HomeComponent,
},
```

Can this be done? If yes how can I call 2 separate HTML's with the same controller using routerLinks...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hope this will help you. Use your buttons as below.

```
<button type="button" [routerLink]="['/homeInfo/',<your id>]" label="Home Info"></button>
```

```
<button type="button" routerLink="/home/" label="Home"></button>
```

In your Home component

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { ActivatedRoute} from '@angular/router';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-home',
  templateUrl: './home.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./home.component.scss']
})
export class HomeComponent implements OnInit {
  constructor(
    private route: ActivatedRoute,
  ) {}

  title: string;
  id: number;

  //Based on these boolean values change HTML controls
  isHomeMode = false;
  isHomeInfoMode = false;

  msgs: any[];

  ngOnInit() {
    this.route.params.subscribe(params => {
      if (this.route.snapshot.url[0].path === 'home') {
        this.title = 'Home';
        this.isHomeMode = true;
      } else {
        this.title = 'Home Info';
        this.isHomeInfoMode = true;
        this.id = params.id;
      }
    });
  } 
}
```

StackBlitz :https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-egkmls

Comment: This returned "This condition will always return 'false' since the types 'UrlSegment' and '"home"' have no overlap" as error on the line this.route.snapshot..

Comment: It's working for me. Here check my Stackblitz https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-egkmls

Comment: Hope you undesrstand better by this example [link](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-egkmls?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html) here I have 2 html files, where my original question was how can I access the 2 .html file by using routerLinks

Comment: You just mentioned my demo link in your above comment

Comment: I think you didn't understand my question well, I'm trying to make a routerLink which gets me to a particular .html(view). Now this .html(view) is inside the same folder as the first .html(view)

Comment: Show me your folder structure. And update your question by adding more code.

Comment: [link](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-qoaj2h) This is what I'm asking for how can I access home.component2.html from home.component.html

Comment: Any specific reason to not to use home.component2.ts file?

Comment: Yes, because in my scenario is to view details of that particular home by using the id which is generated from home.component.html

Comment: So , using another component.ts file, you can achieve your task easily. You have HomeComponent already, add another component called HomeInfoComponent.

Comment: Yep did that and it worked. Just a question, so if I needed to use the same component, would I be able to?

Comment: i haven't gone through such a situation. I'm also still learning.

Comment: Ok cheers, thanks for your time and good luck with your studies!